# How to find the number of differentially expressed genes due to treatment from a dataset whose p-value is already adjusted?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I have a dataset with gene Id, gene name, log2 fold change and raw p-value. How to find the BH  adjusted p-value for each gene? and  How can I find how many have expression was upregulated by treatment by at least 2-fold from the adjusted p-value.The p-value is in column 4 and log2 fold change is in column 3.

Comment: The title says the p-values are already adjusted, but the question says the dataset includes the raw p-value. Do you mean that the p-values in the dataset have already been adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are dealing with raw p-values like your question states, you can use the [`p.adjust`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) function in `R`, which can compute adjusted p-values for a wide variety of correction measures.

I would create a new column called `padj` using `p.adjust` and then filter to only include genes with a `log2FC` greater than 2 and `padj` below your desired alpha threshold.

Using `R`, here is code that computes BH adjusted p-values and then filters based on your criteria. Note that `df` would be your dataframe

````
library(dplyr)
alpha <- .05

diffexp <- df %>%
   mutate(padj = p.adjust(pvalue, method="BH")) %>%
   filter(log2FC > 0, padj < alpha)
```
````

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of choosing log2 fold change greater than 2?

Comment: I interpreted your question as 2 fold from log2 fold change although now I see you said from adjusted p-value. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "at least 2-fold from the adjusted p-value". Could you elaborate? In my field it is common to filter for genes with `padj` < .05 and absolute value of `log2FC` > 2 to prioritize genes with large differential expression and significant evidence to back up the fold change

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a dataset which has the values for the log2 fold change from that dataset I want to see the genes those were upregulated due to treatment. Which I want to see after adjusting the p-values. I am not being able to figure out how to do that in R. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my code to now include **any** genes that are upregulated and considered significant at `padj` < .05. Note this code assumes the non-treatment group was coded as the reference level so that the log2FoldChange values are for the treatment group compared to non-treatment.